# Is there a way to have a druid select an alternate domain with Nature's Bond

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, domains

Is it possible to select an alternate domain (specifically, [Community](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/community-domain/)) using Nature's Bond, without relying on third-party content. Anything published by Paizo is on the table.

I am preparing to play in a Kingmaker Adventure Path game. I am considering playing a Druid dedicated to Erastil. As part of this, I would like to select the Community Domain instead of one of the standard picks for a Druid with the Nature's Bond class feature. My DM is new, and would prefer not to open the floodgates to any 3rd party published content (wise), so I would like possible solutions to be restricted to Paizo-published material.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, the Urban Druid archetype

The [Urban Druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/urban-druid/) (Advanced Players Guide) has access to different domains:

> **Nature Bond (Ex)**
>
> An urban druid may not select an animal companion. Instead, she must choose from the following domains, rather than those usually available to druids: Charm, **Community**, Knowledge, Nobility, Protection, Repose, Rune, or Weather.

### And the Ancient Guardian archetype

The [Ancient Guardian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo-druid-archetypes/ancient-guardian-druid-archetype/) (Monster Codex), also has access to the Community domain:

> **Community Bond (Ex)**
>
> At 1st level, an ancient guardian must choose the domain nature bond ability and select from the following domains: **Community**, Healing, Knowledge, Protection, or Repose.
>
> This ability alters nature bond.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the quick response! Also, love the avatar.